Do ag-charts financial charts support subplots
I've tried to search, so excuse me if this has already been answered.
I'm interested in using the ag-charts financial charts control. I was wondering if this control supports subplots with a shared date xaxis? For example, if i wanted to add and an rsi or MACD indicator to a financial chart?
https://www.ag-grid.com/charts/react/financial-charts/
Regards,
Chris
